# JSON into Tabulator table- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabulator

I am trying to load a JSON from a URL into a Tabulator table. I have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/liostse/2tdtyL6d/

```
var tableData = [];
$.getJSON('http://88.99.13.199:3000/regionsdata', function(mydata) {
  mydata.forEach(function(val) {
    var regdata = {};
    regdata.measure_code = val.measure_code;
    regdata.totalbent = val.totalbent;
    regdata.totalddent = val.totalddent;
    regdata.totaldd = val.totaldd;
    regdata.pctpliromes = val.pctpliromes;
    tableData.push(regdata);
  });
});
$("#mytable").tabulator({
  data: tableData,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  tooltipsHeader: false,
  columns: 
    [{title: "Measure",field: "measure_code",sorter: "string",frozen: true},
    {title: "totalbent",field: "totalbent"},
    {title: "totalddent",field: "totalddent"},
    {title: "totaldd",field: "totaldd"},
    {title: "pctpliromes",field: "pctpliromes"}],
});
```

Notice that, if I use hard-coded data, it works:

```
var tableData = [
   {measure_code:"Μ1",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   {measure_code:"Μ2",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   {measure_code:"Μ3",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   {measure_code:"Μ19",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   {measure_code:"Μ20",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   {measure_code:"Μ97",totalbent:"", totalddent:"", totaldd:"", pctpliromes:""},
   ];
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getJSON is asynchronous, so when you call .tabulator your data are not there yet.
You have to place your call to .tabulator within the getJSON success function, i.e. something like:

```
$.getJSON('http://88.99.13.199:3000/regionsdata', function(mydata) {
  mydata.forEach(function(val) {
    ...
  });
  $("#mytable").tabulator({
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: So obvious! It did not work in my jsfiddle but works fine in my code! Thank you @ykouman (Σε ευχαριστώ! Έχουμε συνεργαστεί στο παρελθόν).

Comment: Σε θυμάμαι πολύ καλά Ηλία! Καλή συνέχεια!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to parse your data outside of Tabulator, you can call the ***setData*** function and pass your url straight into that. Tabulator will take care of the rest.

```
$("#mytable").tabulator("setData", "http://88.99.13.199:3000/regionsdata");
```